# Can EntityFramework execute query even if the schema is not up-to-date

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

For some reasons, I need to connect to an old database (old schema) with an EntityFramework 6 context (Database First approach) up-to-date with the new schema.

Is it possible to tell EntityFramework: execute the query even if you have a bad feeling about it, I am ready to assume the consequences if it is really impossible? I cannot predict which part of the schema is going to be different, so I need a generic solution.

I know I am exposing to unexpected behaviors, exceptions, etc. Basically, my schema changes are new columns and/or missing columns, so it could be possible (in most cases) to fix missing/new columns by setting the mapped property to `default(TEntity)`.

And of course, I cannot update my old database schema :D.

**Edit**

To be exhaustive, my database is a `SQLite` database and here is the exception I am getting when querying a table with a new column:

Query:

```
this.DbSet.FirstOrDefault();
```

Exception:

> SQL logic error or missing database
>
> no such column: Extent1.SalesManager

Comment: Write your query not to select the entire set of fields via .Select() or add `[NotMapped]` to those attributes.

Comment: I don't know which columns are going to be missing or new at runtime. I will add this in the question. Because of that, your suggestion is not possible.

Comment: EF is not designed for that. I suppose you could do some complex reflection. Depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a tool like LinqPad to run your query, and when you get an error, modify your query to address that error.  For instance, if a column doesn't exist, remove that column from your query, and try again.

Comment: Is it possible to do this at runtime? I can see there is NuGet packages but on the LinqPad website, I can't see any runtime API...